# Scaling images in Java to very small dimensions

Tags: java, image, scaling

I am trying to scale "normal" images (like 200*200px) down to small dimensions (10*10px) in a Java application. The images I have to process are characters.
It actually works quite well, the problem is that it makes the characters too thick, compare to the original image.

For example, with this image: [Letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmKDL.png)

If I convert the scaled image to an array of numbers and display it, it will make something like this:

```
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
  ** **  
  *  **  
 ******  
 **  **  
 *** **  
 **  **  
     **
```

I would like the thickness to be 1, instead of 2, because if the character is smaller on the picture, it makes it unusable after scaling.

For this image: [Smaller letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa2JL.png)

This is what comes out:

```
   ** *  
   ***   
  ****   
  ****   
  ** *   
  ****
```

As you can see, the character can't be identified anymore.

Here's my code:

```
public BufferedImage rescaleImage(BufferedImage img, int targetWidth)
{        
    int type = (img.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE) ?
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
    BufferedImage ret = (BufferedImage)img;
    int w = img.getWidth();

    do {
        if (w > targetWidth) {
            w /= 2;
            if (w < targetWidth) {
                w = targetWidth;
            }
        }

        BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(w, w, type);
        Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, w, null);
        g2.dispose();

        ret = tmp;
    } while (w != targetWidth);

    return ret;
}
```

I have tried different parameters in the setRenderingHint method, but I always get either a too thick, or too thin character (some pixels disappear).

Do you know how I could fix this?

Thanks!

LeChocdesGitans